# How can I change the CSS for a question that has a favorite tag?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

I have poor vision. It's hard to notice when a favorite item is in the list. The color seems like a very light yellow/brown.

I tried to find one in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug), but I got lost.

Is there some way to change the color of a question that has one of one's favorite tags so that it has a higher contrast?

Note: I can not seem to find: "tagged-interesting" in the page source view of http://stackoverflow.com in Firefox (I must be doing something really wrong).

edit. here is one from today. maybe someone can see what to do.

```
<div class="question-summary narrow"
     id="question-summary-36895776"


     >
    <div onclick="window.location.href='/questions/36895776/nullpointerexception-at-initializing-webelements-with-findby-using-testng-ja'" class="cp">
        <div class="votes">
            <div class="mini-counts"><span title="1 vote">1</span></div>
            <div>vote</div>
        </div>
        <div class="status unanswered">
            <div class="mini-counts"><span title="0 answers">0</span></div>
            <div>answers</div>
        </div>
        <div class="views">
            <div class="mini-counts"><span title="30 views">30</span></div>
            <div>views</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="summary">

                    <h3><a href="/questions/36895776/nullpointerexception-at-initializing-webelements-with-findby-using-testng-ja" class="question-hyperlink" title="I&#39;m trying to run my tests in Chrome. I&#39;ve been using Firefox until now, and with FF it all worked fine. But now I need to switch to Chrome and I came across with a problem of launching the ...">NullPointerException at initializing WebElements with @FindBy, using TestNG + Java + PageFactory</a></h3>
        <div class="tags t-java t-oop t-inheritance t-selenium-webdriver t-testng">
            <a href="/questions/tagged/java" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;java&#39;" rel="tag">java</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/oop" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;oop&#39;" rel="tag">oop</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/inheritance" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;inheritance&#39;" rel="tag">inheritance</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;selenium-webdriver&#39;" rel="tag">selenium-webdriver</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/testng" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;testng&#39;" rel="tag">testng</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="started">
            <a href="/questions/36895776/nullpointerexception-at-initializing-webelements-with-findby-using-testng-ja" class="started-link">modified <span title="2016-04-28 01:54:23Z" class="relativetime">29 secs ago</span></a>
            <a href="/users/6259229/over9ooo">over9ooo</a> <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">6</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62952/the-highlight-colour-for-interested-tags/62956#62956?

Comment: i have now. still can't find "tagged-interesting" in page view of stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

These favorite questions start with `<div class="question-summary tagged-interesting"` where as other questions are start with just `<div class="question-summary"`. CSS to change favorite's look would be `.tagged-interesting { background-color: ... }`